# PHP - Call two of the same function? Possible?

Tags: php, function, modularity

Is it possible to define the same function in two files, include them and then call both function in one go, e.g.

== File1.php ==

```
function my_function() {
echo "File 1!";
}
```

== File2.php ==

```
function my_function() {
echo "File 2!";
}
```

== File3.php ==

```
include('File1.php');
include('File2.php');
my_function();
```

-
Which would output:

```
File 1!
File 2!
```

Is this is not possible how would I work around that?

Thanks,
Thomas Edwards

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Giving us some context would allow us to give the most appropriate solution :)

Comment: No, this is not possible, and I'm not even sure what it would be useful for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't redefine global functions (*[outside of runkit](http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php), but that's bad voodoo*) so your options remain of using a class driven solution, or an anonymous function driven solution as follows.

You could write a function to assemble all included functions into a call queue (*which is simply another anonymous function that runs the queue*):

```
function queueFunctions(array $functions){
    return function() 
    use ($functions) {
        foreach($functions as $function) {
            $function();
        }
    };
}
```

And return anonymous functions from each of the files as you described, rather than redefine a global function:

**file1.php**

```
return function() {
    echo 'Hello';
};
```

**file2.php**

```
return function() {
    echo 'World';
};
```

Then, you can:

```
// both
$function = queueFunctions([
    include('file1.php'), 
    include('file2.php'),
]);

$function(); // HelloWorld

// one of them    
$function = queueFunctions([
    include('file2.php'),
]);

$function(); // World

// repeated calls
$function = queueFunctions([
    include('file2.php'),
    include('file1.php'),
    include('file2.php'),
]);

$function(); // WorldHelloWorld
```

Answer (score 3):

It wouldn't. You would get an cannot redclare function error. You have to use the methods of classes instead, they can have the same names.

Answer (score 2):

This will not work because both methods have the same signature. In other words PHP does not know which method to call first and thus produces an error.

What you could do however is create some objects which have a method with the same name, store them in a list and then cycle through them.

The following is untested but the principle is there.

```
// Abstract class acts as a common interface to allow using the same method name
abstract class MyAbstract {  
    abstract function my_function();
}  

class FirstClass {
    function my_function() {
        echo "Class 1!";
    }
}

class SecondClass {
    function my_function() {
        echo "Class 2!";
    }
}

$objectArray[] = new FirstClass();
$objectArray[] = new SecondClass();

foreach($objectArray as $object){
    $object->my_function();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, Its not possible. You will get an ERROR because you called same function twice.